# How to configure a core and/or JMS bridge programmatically?

Tags: jms, hornetq

I want to find a way to configure a core bridge (and, if possible, JMS) between two HornetQ instances programmatically.

There are easy to use embedding tutorials in the HornetQ documentation, but none of them describes how to add a core bridge to the equation. Furthermore, there is BridgeConfiguration class available, but it is just a POJO, placeholder for the configuration itself and I can't make it up and running with HornetQ instance. Especially, among others, defining connections seems to be puzzling.

Please, help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this weak answer, I have never tried this myself. But create a `BrideConfiguration` instance, set it's properties and add it to the bridge configuration list.

```
Configuration.getBridgeConfigurations().add(bridgeConfiguration)
```

I hope this can at least give some hint about how this can be achieved.